# Why can't I delete the ~/.vscode-server directory even when there are no vscode processes found?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh

```
# Command won't succeed so I assume that a vscode process could be running
rm -rf ~/.vscode-server/
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/$USER/.vscode-server/bin/4cb974a7aed77a74c7813bdccd99ee0d04901215/vscode-server-linux-x64/node_modules/readable-stream’: Directory not empty
```

I've already read through several articles with potential solutions, and none worked.  I have already tried to search for vscode process in multiple ways such as:

```
#finds nothing
lsof | grep $HOME/.vscode-server | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -u

ps aux | grep .vscode
shawn.f+ 41466  0.0  0.0 112816   972 pts/1    S+   10:38   0:00 grep .vscode

# Don't include the actual grep in the search and it finds nothing
ps aux | grep .vscode | grep -v grep
```

What else can I try?  I've no idea what is blocking me from removing this directory.

It has something to do with nodejs because ~/.vscode-server/bin/4cb974a7aed77a74c7813bdccd99ee0d04901215/vscode-server-linux-x64/node_modules has sub-directories that are getting created periodically.  I believe that is the source of the error but I am not finding any process that I own related to vscode or node.